# Facebook client side permanent access token

Tags: jquery, facebook, json

I am using JSON to retrieve Facebook album to create a gallery.

As the gallery is not public so I use `access token` which works perfect but it expires after a while.

I would like to know is it possible to get permanent access token?

This is how I retrieved json

```
https://graph.facebook.com/346138265459638/photos?access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAHjZCqytFok9nvE9ubvpQNS1RWZANIjTz3aYUnIC7bVsvOL8idm9BQRCR3y7L5XRLWtpkekqMSpoVZCOZCWpNccY6ag2K8AFHu9kBQXZC
```

This is what I got some information from but I could not figure out.

```
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/
```

Comment: If what you're looking for is a non-expiring page access token, I just got this worked out over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168452/long-lasting-fb-access-token-for-server-to-pull-fb-page-info

Comment: You can get a non-expiring *page* access token, but *user* access tokens are valid for 60-days maximum.

Comment: how to get non-expiring token?

Answer (score 0):

So, if you are trying to do this for a user photo album, there is no such thing as non-expiring access tokens. If you are trying to do this for a page, there are non-expiring tokens, but you need to retrieve a long-lived one from the user first, then request one for the page...

The documentation to do all of this is located here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/