# Facebook page post as admin using javascript api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I do lots of stuff in my javascript code for posting feed in page as m`, but how i can get permission through javascript with just one click.

This is my code.

```
<body>
<div id='fb-root'></div>
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
<p>
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Group</a>
</p>
<p id='msg'></p>

<script> 
  FB.init({appId: "apid", status: true, cookie: true});
  function postToFeed() {
  FB.api('/page_id/feed', 'post', 
             { 
                 message     : "It's awesome ...",
                 link        : 'http://csslight.com',
                 picture     : 'http://csslight.com/application/upload/WebsitePhoto/567-grafmiville.png',
                 name        : 'Featured of the Day',
                 from: 'pageid',
                 description : 'CSS Light is a showcase for web design encouragement, submitted by web designers of all over the world. We simply accept the websites with high quality and professional touch.'
         }, 
         function(response) {
             alert(JSON.stringify(response));
         });
  }
  </script>
  </body>
```

Output of above script is

[image]

But i wan't to post as a `BeCrazzy.com` not Rajnish..!

simply, i want to post feed in page as a admin. please help me. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to post to Facebook fanpage as fanpage, not user](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8034753/how-to-post-to-facebook-fanpage-as-fanpage-not-user)

Comment: I guess my answer above is still valid.

Comment: Yes, you are right but i have litle bit confusion..
How to get access token using javascript api...sorry i can't get any solution.

Comment: My code in the above answer is exactly getting this! Have you tried it? read the document posted in the answer below (on how to login a user and get their `manage_pages` & `publish_stream` permission and after that my answer would 1) get a page access token 2) post as a page.

Comment: thanxs budy, finaly i have done ...:) using php-sdk.

Comment: @Rajnish i also stopped on these step.. why can;t do in javascript... any know///???
|

Comment: @ifaour how to i get page access token ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tutorial here that shows you exactly how to do this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/

You will not be able to use the Facebook Javascript SDK to make the API call signed with the Page access token, you'll need to use something like jQuery.ajax() to do so.

Comment: There is sample code in the guide, please at least attempt to follow it.

Comment: This post helped me with the access token:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168452/long-lasting-fb-access-token-for-server-to-pull-fb-page-info/21927690#21927690