# Posting video on facebook page?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

is it possible to write an automated script that uploads a specific video to a specific facebook page without any user action, like login verification and "Do you want to allow App XY to post something on your wall"?

I looked a bit into the Facebook PHP SDK, and there are a couple of things I dont like:

1) You always have to verify that you want to post something on your page

2) It seems it can't be run from localhost, you need a server. That would make the whole thing slower as I had to upload a video to a server before uploading it to facebook.

Another question: Is it possible to "save" the facebook logins, so i can switch pages? Otherwise I just would use multiple .php files.

Comment: Voting to close as “to broad”, because it doesn’t look like you really have looked into it yet (otherwise there shouldn’t be such misconceptions or trivial questions left).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CBroe said, your question looks quite broad. But anyway, have a look at my answer here [Obtaining a Facebook auth token for a command-line (desktop) application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978728/obtaining-a-facebook-auth-token-for-a-command-line-desktop-application/22146640#22146640) to get an idea how this can be solved.