# How to get debug access token

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created WPF Application on C# using Facebook C# SDK. How can I get a debug access token programmatically? I know only one way: through Graph API Explorer. I change "Get Access Token" and copy it in my application. But how to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Login docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0 You have to create a so-called OAuth Login flow to be able to gather Access Tokens for your app.

For a description on how to get Access Tokens on desktop applications, see my answer here: [Obtaining a Facebook auth token for a command-line (desktop) application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978728/obtaining-a-facebook-auth-token-for-a-command-line-desktop-application/22146640#22146640)