# Facebook Graphs API returns session invalid

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I would like to use Facebook Graph API in my android app. I'm trying to see if I can log in to Facebook using an Access Token which [never expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168452/long-lasting-fb-access-token-for-server-to-pull-fb-page-info), but my code always return `Session is Invalid`. Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong in the following code? thanks

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Facebook fb;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fb = new Facebook(getString(R.string.APP_ID));
        fb.setAccessToken(getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN));
        //Expiry is set to 0, since the token never expires
        fb.setAccessExpires(0);



        if (fb.isSessionValid()) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Session is valid",
                    android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("TAG2", getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN));

        } else
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Session is Invalid"+ getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN),
                    android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("TAG3", getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN));


    }

}
```

Comment: According to this source : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/Facebook.java, the method *setAccessToken* is deprecated

Comment: @PhatH.VU I know it is deprecated that's why i have put Suppress Warning but it doesn't answer why I can seem to get a valid session. How can I get a valid session using an existing Access Token?