# How to create session using FB page access token

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I created a [long-lasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168452/long-lasting-fb-access-token-for-server-to-pull-fb-page-info) Facebook access token. I have a TestApp's app ID from Facebook. The issue is that I can't seem to get a valid session! What am I doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Facebook fb;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fb = new Facebook(getString(R.string.APP_ID));
        fb.setAccessToken(getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN));
        //Expiry is set to 0, since the token never expires
        fb.setAccessExpires(0);



        if (fb.isSessionValid()) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Session is valid",
                    android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("TAG2", getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN));

        } else
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Session is Invalid"+ getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN),
                    android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("TAG3", getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN));


    }

}
```

**Edited Code**  (I edited my original code to reflect the two answers given, but still it didn't help):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Facebook fb;
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
         editor.putString("AKEY",getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN));
         editor.commit();
         editor.apply();

        fb = new Facebook(getString(R.string.app_id));
        fb.setAccessToken(prefs.getString("AKEY", ""));
        //Expiry is set to 0, since the token never expires
        fb.setAccessExpires(0);

        if (fb.isSessionValid()) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Session is validd",
                    android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("TAG2", getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN));

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, fb.toString(),
                    android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("TAG3", fb.toString() + fb.getAccessExpires()
                    + "Access Token is: " + fb.getAccessToken() +prefs.getString("AKEY", "")
                    + "Last update is:" + fb.getLastAccessUpdate()
                    + "Session is:" + fb.getSession());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: is there a reason why you are using old API?

Comment: @ItzikSamara No, I thought this was the standard way to get a session using FB's API.

Comment: if is it possible for you to add the Facebook Loginbutton i will write down full answer.

Comment: @ItzikSamara Actually I just need to get the status from one page which I manage. Thats why i created the long-lasting token to just allow me monitor the page. Nobody else will be using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only explaination for this behaviour that I could think is that I was using a deprecated API. After having changed my code according to the new API it works now. Would have appreciated it had this been made clear in the Facebook documentation.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences prefs;

    Session session;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("AKEY",getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN));
        editor.putLong("expire", 0);
        editor.commit();
        editor.apply();

        Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback()
                       {
           @Override
           public void call(
               Session session,
               SessionState state,
               Exception exception)
           {
             // safety check
             if (isFinishing())
               return;

             // check session state

             if (state.equals(SessionState.CLOSED)
                 || state.equals(SessionState.CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED))
             {
             //  clearFacebookInfoFromSharedPreferences();
                 Log.d("TAG A","clearFacebookInfoFromSharedPreferences()");

               // specific action for when the session is closed
               // because an open-session request failed
               if (state.equals(SessionState.CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED))
               {

                   Log.d("TAG B","cancelProgressDialog()");

               }
             }
             else if (state.equals(SessionState.OPENED))
             {
             //  cancelProgressDialog();


               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Succeeded connecting to Facebook",    android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


               //handler.onSuccess();
             }
           }
         };

if (Session.getActiveSession() == null
                  && prefs.contains("AKEY")
                  && prefs.contains("expire"))
              {
                // open a session from the access token info
                // saved in the app's shared preferences

                String accessTokenString = prefs.getString(
                    "AKEY",
                    "");

                Date accessTokenExpires = new Date(prefs.getLong(
                    "expire",
                    0));

                AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.createFromExistingAccessToken(
                    accessTokenString,
                    accessTokenExpires,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);

                session=Session.openActiveSessionWithAccessToken(this, accessToken, callback);

            if (session != null) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Session is valid",
                    android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("TAG2", ""+session.getExpirationDate()+session.getAccessToken());

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Session is invalid",
                    android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }




            Bundle params = new Bundle();

            params.putString("fields", "likes.limit(1).summary(true)");
            Request request = new Request(session, "922169881132606", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    try {
                        Log.d("TAG5", "In Try block");
                        GraphObject go = response.getGraphObject();
                        Log.d("graph object is", go.toString());
                        JSONObject obj = go.getInnerJSONObject();
                        JSONObject arr = obj.getJSONObject("likes"); 
                        JSONObject res = arr.getJSONObject("summary");
                        Log.d("TAG23", "JSON Set");
                       int numberOfLikes = res.getInt("total_count");
                       Log.d("Number of likes is ", Integer.toString(numberOfLikes));
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Number of likes is",
                                android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("An error was thrown","alpha"+e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
           Log.d("TAG7", "task is executed");





    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SharedPreference to store the session in Android.

**Store**

```
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("KEY_NAME",
                context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putInt("fbsession", session);
editor.commit();
editor.apply();
```

**Retrieve**

```
 SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("KEY_NAME", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 String fbSession = settings.getInt("fbsession", 1);
```

Comment: Could you give more details? What do you mean store the session? As you can see from the code, a valid session is simply not returned.

Comment: I tried the solution you provided, but I still have the issue. I have posted the edited code.

Answer (score 0):

**You can code like this to put value in prefs**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.projectname.pkgname",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putString("facebook_accesstoken", "your_token").commit();
```

**and get it like this**

```
String facebook_accessstoken=prefs.getString("facebook_accesstoken", "");
```

Comment: lazy guy please do it own

Comment: I tried the solution you provided, but I still have the issue. I have posted the edited code.