# Facebook Posting to Page Wall gives an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, koala-gem

I am using koala gem in rails 3. I used the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21927690/506338) to get the permanent access token for my page. And I have given all permissions to this access token for my testing purposes.

```
public_profile, basic_info, read_stream, read_mailbox, read_page_mailboxes, rsvp_event,
email, read_insights, manage_notifications, manage_pages, publish_actions, user_birthday, 
user_religion_politics, user_relationships, user_hometown, user_location, user_likes, 
user_activities, user_interests, user_education_history, user_work_history, user_website, 
user_groups, user_events, user_photos, user_videos, user_friends, user_about_me, 
user_status, user_games_activity, user_tagged_places, user_actions.books, 
user_actions.music, user_actions.video, user_actions.news
```

Now from the rails console I do the following:

```
access_token = "some_string"
@user = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
@attachment = {:name => "Link name", :link => "http://www.example.com/", :caption => "{*actor*} posted a new review", :description => "This is a longer description of the attachment"}
@user.put_wall_post("This is some text", @attachment)
```

The action returns the following:

```
Koala::Facebook::ClientError: type: GraphMethodException, code: 100, message: Unsupported post request. [HTTP 400]
```

But my page wall does show the post. I am wondering what may be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out my application was not published so all calls were returning an error. Changing the application status resulted in fixing the issue.