# Facebook API "This Ads API call requires the user to be admin of the application"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I can successfully pull statistics from the FB API using the temporary access token, however I followed the instructions to generate a token that never expires from this thread.

[Long-lasting FB access-token for server to pull FB page info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168452/long-lasting-fb-access-token-for-server-to-pull-fb-page-info)

It does indeed work. But then when trying to using this Page token I get the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException' with message '(#272) This Ads API call requires the user to be admin of the application. User XXXXXX not admin or developer for application XXXXXXX.' in

```
C:\www\projects\dashboard2014\vendor\facebook\php-ads-sdk\src\FacebookAds\Http\Exception\RequestException.php on line 129
```

However the user is an Admin of the application! I can see it in the application settings. Also I can see the token has the following permissions:

```
"perms": [
    "EDIT_PROFILE",
    "CREATE_CONTENT",
    "MODERATE_CONTENT",
    "CREATE_ADS",
    "BASIC_ADMIN"
]
```

In the App settings I also put the Ad account ID in the "Authorized Ad Account IDs" field and this doesn't work still.

If I use the temporary access token from the Graph API Explorer then I am able to pull in data from any campaign in the ad account with no problem, the problems seems to be that this is a Page access token, so there's a slight difference somewhere but I can't seem to work it out?

I don't mind having a different long life access token for every Page rather than just one for the whole account however it's not working. Thanks