# How to post to my own page using the Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to post updates to a Facebook Page I own, using the API.

I followed the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28418469/517371) to obtain:

1. a *short-lived access token* for my user, making sure to grant permissions for publish_stream and manage_pages
2. a *long-lived access token*, which the token debugger actually shows as never expiring
3. a *Permanent Page Access Token* specific for my page, which again is shown as never expiring

I can use the long-lived access token to post to my wall, but neither that nor the specific page access token allow me to post to my page.

If I try to use the personal long-lived access token to post to my Page ID, it returns OK and an actual post ID, but the post never appears on the page.

If I try to use the page access token to post either to `/me/feed` (which should be the page) or to the page ID, I get **#200 The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action** which I clearly did.

What am I doing wrong?

Do I need to submit my app for review? How can I do so, when I don't even have an "app"? It has no public facing website, nothing, because it's only a single script for my own personal use, which I'd like to use to update my page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed#pubperms) you will need `publish_pages` permission to post as page from api v2.3 . Prior, it needed permission `publish_actions` in addition to `manage_pages`. Now they have introduced `publish_pages` specifically for that purpose.  .

> A page access token with `publish_pages` permission can be used to
>   publish new posts on behalf of that page. Posts will appear in the
>   voice of the page.

Comment: Thank you. That was it. It still gives me a warning box when I grant the permission, saying *"Your app may break after 30 April 2015"* (**may** or **will**?) and *"Some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by Facebook."* So do I still need to submit my script for review? Are there any guidelines for self-developed scripts, which are not actual apps?

Comment: @Tobia facebook approval is meant for general public . The app owner , developers and test accounts won't be affected.

Comment: That's what I hope. My FB account owns both the app and the Page, so let's hope they don't block my app updating my own page.

Comment: _“Prior this permission was automatically granted when obtaining page access token”_ – no; before v2.3, it needed permission `publish_actions` in addition to `manage_pages`. Now they have introduced `publish_pages` specifically for that purpose.

Comment: @Toby so, did you need permission approval for posting to your own page?

Comment: @Tobia I would also appreciate if you could let HendyIrawan and I know if permission approval was required to post to your own page. Cheers