# Video Upload to Facebook via Koala

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to implement a small script, which would automatically upload and post videos on our Facebook page. I got the token as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168452/long-lasting-fb-access-token-for-server-to-pull-fb-page-info/21927690#21927690). But when I try to upload a video, I get the error

```
   No permission to publish the video [HTTP 400] (Koala::Facebook::ClientError)
```

I have the following permissions for the page:

```
     user_friends, manage_pages, public_profile

     "perms": [
        "ADMINISTER",
        "EDIT_PROFILE",
        "CREATE_CONTENT",
        "MODERATE_CONTENT",
        "CREATE_ADS",
        "BASIC_ADMIN"
     ]
```

How can I solve that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

"Publish_action" permission for post status with Images or Videos. It Should Work.

Comment: and how/where could I add it?

Comment: Ok, as I understand, I need to submit the app to review in order to activate this, but the thing is, I do not need a working app, I just need permissions to post to our corporate FB page..

Comment: 1. Here is the example how and where you can use that permission(Hope you got other things)
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=123456789&redirect_uri=http://localhost:1234&response_type=token&scope=publish_actions

2. If you want to post status to page by one account means if that account is developer or owner of the app means you no need to submit your app for review.

Comment: If this answer helps means you can select above answer as correct.