# Webhooks for Lead Ads working but api call to get form values don't

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So, I've created a Webhook with Facebook for my Ads Leads. It is working - I'm receiving the Webhook with the RTUs.

The problem is when I call the api to retrieve the data associated with the form. I'm using the leadgen_id to call the api and I'm gettin:

`Unsupported get request. Object with ID '' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api`

The point is: when I test it here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lead-ads-testing the leadgen_id that is returned works with my API calls and I can access the form data that I need.
But when I try with the leadgen_id that I receive from users registering in my ads, it returns the error message.

Any idea of how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.  I was able to get this to work by giving my System User 'Manage Page' access and 'Leads Access' in Business Manager.

1. Add your System User to the Page with 'Manage Page' access.

- Business Manager > Business Settings > Accounts > Pages, and select the Page you are working with from the list.
- Click 'Add People,' select your System User, and toggle 'Manage Page' setting.

2. Add your System User to Leads Access.

- Business Manager > Business Settings > Integrations > Leads Access, and select the Page you are working with from the list.
- Click 'Add People, and select your System User.

Comment: Yes, We have faced the same issue with our many customers. We got the same response from FB support as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. This sounds like missing 'scopes' on the access token you are using to make the Graph API call. Generally, for webhooks you need a few scopes, these are the ones I currently have on my webhook:

   pages_manage_cta, pages_show_list, ads_management, leads_retrieval, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_metadata, pages_read_user_content, pages_manage_ads, pages_manage_engagement, public_profile

You can use the Access Token Debugger tool to see the list of scopes on your access token (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/)

2. Your Graph API access token might have expired. To setup a permanent access token follow the instructions on here: [Long-lasting FB access-token for server to pull FB page info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168452/long-lasting-fb-access-token-for-server-to-pull-fb-page-info)